# Symfony 3.4 : Could not load type "form": class does not exist

Tags: symfony

I'm looking to upgrade an old project from Symfony version 2.8 to version 3.4. I made the most important changes but when running trough /web/app_dev.php I get this error in one of the project custom Controllers:  "Could not load type "form": class does not exist."  . I tried to check out the FormFactory.php class but could not find any errors.

This is working flawless  in version 2.8,  does anyone have a clue about why this is happening in version 3.4 ?

I'm running php 5.6 with Symfony 3.4.49  .

Here is a printshot of the issue: https://prnt.sc/1xh57dh

### Thanks a lot.

FormFactory->createNamedBuilder('search_form', 'form', object(Assignment)) in src/AppBundle/Controller/.....Controller.php (line 78)

```
        if ($incomingClient != '') {
            $clients[] = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:Client')->find($incomingClient);
        }
        $form = $this->get('form.factory')->createNamedBuilder('search_form', 'form', $entity)
        
            ->add('client', 'entity', array(
                'class' => 'AppBundle:Client',
                'required' => false,
                'empty_value' => 'Search clients',
```

Comment: Have you checked the upgrade documents? In any case, stop using PHP 5.6!

Comment: Have you read the UPGRADE document? https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/3.4/UPGRADE-3.0.md#form